# Database contents in different pages like same layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-adapterview

Showing database rows as ListView/Gridview in the same layout via adapter, is there a option to display those in separate pages like same layout. So I can switch to next page by a button. 
Currently am just saving values using sharedprefernce and changes the contents from layout (Just **TEXT** in my case).  I am trying to create app for exam tests with a question and 4 options. currently am saving user score and checked radio button id in sharedpreferences when user click NEXT button.
My code:

```
package com.sap.quizmaster;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MyDatabase testdb;
private Cursor mycursor;

private TextView ques;

private RadioGroup options;
private RadioButton op1;
private RadioButton op2;
private RadioButton op3;
private RadioButton op4;
private RadioButton radioButton;

private LinearLayout default_lay;
private LinearLayout default_btn_lay;
private TextView final_text;
private Button final_btn;

private Button next_btn;
private Button prev_btn;

private int checkedid = -1;
private int q_no = 1;
private String answer;
private int score = 0;

private SharedPreferences sp;
private SharedPreferences.Editor sp_edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ques = findViewById(R.id.ques);
    op1 = findViewById(R.id.op1);
    op2 = findViewById(R.id.op2);
    op3 = findViewById(R.id.op3);
    op4 = findViewById(R.id.op4);
    next_btn = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
    prev_btn = findViewById(R.id.prev_btn);
    options = findViewById(R.id.options);
    final_btn = findViewById(R.id.final_btn);
    final_text = findViewById(R.id.final_text);
    default_lay = findViewById(R.id.default_text);
    default_btn_lay = findViewById(R.id.default_btn);

    //Loading sharedpreferences
    sp = getSharedPreferences("QuizMaster", MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Clearing all values from sharedpreferences when app re-launching
    sp_edit = sp.edit();
    sp_edit.clear();
    sp_edit.commit();

    testdb = new MyDatabase(this);
    mycursor = testdb.getQuestion(q_no);
    setQuestion();

    next_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mycursor.close();

            checkedid = options.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            saveInteger(q_no, checkedid);
            if (checkedid != -1) {
                radioButton = findViewById(checkedid);
                if (radioButton.getText().equals(answer)) {
                    score += 3;
                } else {
                    score -= 1;
                }
            }
            options.clearCheck();
            q_no = q_no + 1;
            if(q_no>3){
                default_btn_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                default_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                final_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final_text.setText("Your Score is "+score);
                q_no = 1;
                return;
            }


                checkedid = sp.getInt(q_no + "", -1);
                if (checkedid != -1) {
                    radioButton = findViewById(checkedid);
                    radioButton.setChecked(true);
                }
                mycursor = testdb.getQuestion(q_no);
                setQuestion();
        }
    });
    prev_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mycursor.close();

            if (q_no <= 1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "END", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            q_no = q_no - 1;
            mycursor = testdb.getQuestion(q_no);
            setQuestion();

            checkedid = sp.getInt(q_no + "", -1);
            if (checkedid != -1) {
                radioButton = findViewById(checkedid);
                radioButton.setChecked(true);

                if (radioButton.getText().equals(answer)) {
                    score -= 3;
                } else {
                    score += 1;
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button PREVIOUS pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    final_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            final_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            default_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            default_btn_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mycursor = testdb.getQuestion(q_no);
            setQuestion();
            sp_edit = sp.edit();
            sp_edit.clear();
            sp_edit.commit();
            score = 0;
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    testdb.close();
    mycursor.close();
}

public void setQuestion() {
    answer = mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("ANS"));

    ques.setText(mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("QUES")));
    op1.setText(mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("OP1")));
    op2.setText(mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("OP2")));
    op3.setText(mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("OP3")));
    op4.setText(mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("OP4")));
}

public void saveInteger(int ques, int value) {
    sp_edit = sp.edit();
    sp_edit.putInt(ques + "", value);
    sp_edit.apply();
}


}
```

**Just get me an link or idea to think in any easy way.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use an AdapterViewFlipper
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterViewFlipper
with a custom adapter

This will generate a view from a template using data from the adapter
e.g. Each question could be on a separate page with a button to move to the next question.

Example https://abhiandroid.com/ui/adapterviewflipper

But you probably don't want to use the autoflipping option and instead link a next button to the `showNext()` method